# log="y" convert only y-axis label or also y-coordinates of my data?

Tags: r, logging, plot

I'm building a plot in R and I have used the plot() function, with log="y" parameter. 
Does that mean that ONLY the y-axis labels will be converted in log scale OR that also the y-coordinates of my data will be converted in log-scale?

Thank you

Comment: It's not entirely clear (to me) what you're asking. Please add a reproducible example and formulate a precise question. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 for hints at how to ask a great R question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `log = "y"` it plots the log-transformed y-values with the labels on the original scale -- the opposite of what you seem to suggest.

Compare these three plots:

```
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- 2*exp(x) + rexp(50)

plot(x, y)            # y-scale,     y-scale-labels
plot(x, y, log = "y") # log-y-scale, y-scale-labels
plot(x, log(y))       # log-y-scale, log-y-scale labels
```

Notice that the last two plots only differs in the y-axis labels. Both are still correct as the axis *titles* are also different.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean. I would like to know what you think, but I guess that if i use log scale for my data, it doesn't make sense use y-scale label. no? or may be is it good if I want to see the data in a clearer way, but keeping the original scale of my y-values.

Comment: @user29859 It's perfectly fine to plot on a log-y-scale but keep the labels on the original scale (`log = "x"`). I prefer it, unless there's a good reason not to do it. Then readers don't have to mentally compute `exp(label)` to read the plot.

Comment: Yes, I agree with as I edited my previous comment. It is good if I want to see the data in a clearer way (log-scale), but keeping the original scale of my y-values.

Comment: Sorry, I have a second question linked to that. The log="" is a logarithm base 10?